# I have a code which is correct in a 3 years back flutter but not in the current flutter version

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

This is a class UniqueId which is a valueobject. This is for checking equality and all that

```
class UniqueId extends ValueObject<String> {
      @override
      final Either<ValueFailure<String>, String> value;
    
      factory UniqueId() {
        return UniqueId._(
          Right(const Uuid().v1())
        );
      }
      factory UniqueId.fromUniqueString(String uniqueId) {
        return UniqueId._(Right(uniqueId));
      }
    
     const UniqueId._(
        this.value,
      );
    }
```

Then I have used freezed.

```
@freezed
abstract class User1 with _$User1{
  const factory User1(
    {required UniqueId id,}
  ) = _User1;
}
```

Now I am giving the part I am having problem with

```
@LazySingleton(as: IauthFailure)
class FirebaseAuthFailure implements IauthFailure {
  final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn;

  FirebaseAuthFailure(this.firebaseAuth, this.googleSignIn); 
  @override
  Future<Option<User1>> getSignedInUser() =>
      firebaseAuth.currentUser().then((firebaseUser) => 
      optionOf(firebaseUser?.toDomain()));
```

The error I am getting is given below:
error1:  The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null'.
solution I used:

```
 @override
  Future<Option<User1>> getSignedInUser() =>
      firebaseAuth.currentUser!().then((firebaseUser) => optionOf(firebaseUser?.toDomain()));
```

error2:the expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.
solution I used:

```
 @override
  Future<Option<User1>> getSignedInUser() =>
      firebaseAuth.currentUser!.then((firebaseUser) => optionOf(firebaseUser?.toDomain()));
```

error3:The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'User'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'then'.
solution I used: Cannot find a solution
The definition of `toDomain()` is :

```
extension FirebaseUserDomainX on User {
  User1 toDomain() {
    return User1(id: UniqueId.fromUniqueString(uid));
  }
}
```

Actually I am not getting this `toDomain` when I am hovering over it and click go to definition its saying no defintion.

Comment: Long ago, the firebase "current user" needed some time, so it got returned by a Future.  Modern firebase gets current user without Future.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood it correctly (your question is not very clear), you should update your code accordingly to deprecated methods.
currentUser is not a method anymore, but it is a getter.
also I'm assuming `_firebaseAuth` is an instance of `FirebaseAuth`

```
@override
Future<Option<User>> getSignedInUser() async {
  User? firebaseUser = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
  return optionOf(firebaseUser?.toDomain());
}
```

It would be very valuable if you posted the error that you're getting when using `optionOf`

Comment: I have edited my question and added few more things

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution of this error this code is deprecated. that's why is not working properly.

```
@override
  Future<Option<User1>> getSignedInUser() =>
      firebaseAuth.currentUser!.then((firebaseUser) => optionOf(firebaseUser?.toDomain()));
```

**see this solution and try it. I have made a simple solution for the deprecated code it's run properly.**

```
  @override
  Future<Option<User>> getSignedInUser() async {
    final firebaseUser = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      return optionOf(firebaseUser.toDomain());
    } else {
      return none();
    }
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).